# If God does not exist then would God's heaven be classified as an "empty world"?

Tags: theology, terminology, nothing

If God does not exist then would God's heaven, in the phrase "God is in his heaven" be classified as an "empty world"?

I have only encountered the phrase "empty world" in [the SEP article on nothingness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness/).

Comment: It is not a matter of theology but only of syntax : If God does not exist, then "His *whatever*" has no meaning.

Comment: Is a sort of playing with words (as in most cases of similar questions...). Unicorns do not exist; thus the unicorn's horn does not exist. But this does not mean that horns do not exist.

Comment: @mauroallegranza I'd +1 the "as in most cases of similar questions" if I could. See https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5032/37256

Comment: The word "heaven" may mean "the sky", in which case is not an "empty world" (what is an empty world ?). The word [Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven_in_Christianity) means "the location of the throne of God as well as the holy angels", in which case its existence is subject to specific religious/theological views.

Comment: i think you're all wrong again... if it's a theology question, then migrate it to christianity stack exchange and ask it there. if not, then quit your whining @Rusi

Comment: your analogy is awful tbh @MauroALLEGRANZA a much, much better one is "the Unicorn's horn does not exist (God) so is the Unicorn nothing/ness (where God "is" and what makes him God). that's a highly cogent question, imvho, please trust me on this

Comment: and i doubt the phrase "God's heaven" has no "meaning", rather than no real referent @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: That SEP article isn't great, using "empty world" without defining it. If someone knows another reference for it can you add it?

Comment: That's a great question. If God does not exist, then {God} is the empty set. If not, not. A thorny problem in set theory.

Comment: can we imply that His heaven is the only empty world? @user4894 that sounds insane haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP notes:

> I'm just asking about the terminology for 'empty world', not whether anyone agrees that God exists or if He is in his heaven (a note in a handout I got in second year classes)

An empty world may be viewed as an impossible world. Here is Wikipedia's description:

> In philosophical logic, the concept of an impossible world (sometimes non-normal world) is used to model certain phenomena that cannot be adequately handled using ordinary possible worlds. An impossible world, w, is the same sort of thing as a possible world (whatever that may be), except that it is in some sense "impossible."

It might also be viewed as a [non-normal world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_world#Non-normal_modal_logics).

---

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, August 16). Impossible world. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 17:51, September 9, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Impossible_world&oldid=911121463

Comment: Hey Frank, I don't believe an impossible world is an empty world. They are two different thing. One is a logical entity, while what OP is referring to is a non-sensical concoction of OPs mind. Regards

Comment: i'm not sure it's just a concoction of my own mind, and i'm not sure why i got that impression from you @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost

Comment: @another_name Well, an empty world, at least logically speaking, is just a Universe without any elements. The heaven you speak of turns out to be a quantified dummy when formalized. I will do that once I get time. Regards

Comment: that's great, thanks. @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost incidentally it's robert browning

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: your answer is missing the crucial point: if God is impossible (or some of his attributes are) is the world's he's in "in some sense impossible"?

Comment: @another_name That's how I was viewing it, but there may be better descriptions of the empty world idea you are trying to describe than what my answer offers. All I hope is that it provides some suggestions to explore.

Comment: what could empty world mean aside from impossible world? @FrankHubeny i'll accept it for now, though tbh i wish you'd made the inference (God is impossible so His heaven is so it is an empty world) clear, even if you just chose to set it off from the rest of the question. that'd validate the question and answer format, imvho

Comment: @another_name As BertrandWittgensteinsGhost suggests it could be something else than what I described although I don't know what that would be. There may be a modal logic that considers such worlds.

Comment: do you mean a logically -- rather than metaphysically or physically -- impossible world?

Comment: @another_name I am thinking of this in terms of semantics for modal logics.

Comment: isn't 'possible world' a semantic for modal logic? i'm not arguing (at all) just trying to work out the discussion. which we can delete shortly